# How to Move Parent Div Position using css on hover

Tags: html, css

Anyone have solution for this i want to move div position via css on mouse hover move div down when i mouse over on div....

**HTML**

```
 <div class="movediv">I Want to Move this div on hover via css</div>
<div class="testing">
<a class="Linktohover">Test</a>
    <div class="showDiv">
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .showDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
.testing:hover .showDiv {
    left: 0px;
    display: block !important;
}
.testing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.movediv {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhaval17/P2aTj/)

Comment: If you change your HTML than yes I can give you a solution

Comment: When i mouse hover on test i want to move div ".movediv"

Comment: Yes, thats what am saying, if you willing to change your markup order I can give you a solution

Comment: No Dear HTML is fixed structure that's why i have posted other wise it's easy to move :)

Comment: So you cannot do that with CSS only

Comment: Hummm that's i know but it's client needs this only by css

Comment: Tell him that either let you go for JS, or change the markup, if he still doesn't agree, tell him to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this types

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YYhTS/)**

```
.container 
   {
    position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
    margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;
    width:50%; height:10%;
   }
.a {position:absolute; bottom:0; left:20px; width:30%;}
.b 
   {
    position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
    margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; width:30%;
   }
.c {position:absolute; bottom:0; right:20px; width:30%;}

.b:hover ~ .a{
-moz-transform:translatex(-50px);
-ms-transform:translatex(-50px);
-o-transform:translatex(-50px);
-webkit-transform:translatex(-50px);
transform:translatex(-50px);
}

.b:hover ~ .c{
-moz-transform:translatex(50px);
-ms-transform:translatex(50px);
-o-transform:translatex(50px);
-webkit-transform:translatex(50px);
transform:translatex(50px);
}
```

Comment: See i want like this 

Acctuly when i mouse over on image i want to move parent image via css

http://jsfiddle.net/dhaval17/EAJMt/

Comment: Hi @Fags your answer is near to my question but not exact becasue when there is parent div and that i want to move by hover current element i can find child divs but coudn't found parent via css to move position or xyz :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.movediv:hover { margin-top:30px;}
```

instead of

```
.movediv{ margin-top:30px;}
```

Comment: When i mouse hover on test i want to move div ".movediv"

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
.showDiv{ position:absolute; left:-9999px; display:block !important; font-size:14px !important;}
.testing:hover .showDiv{ left:0px; display:block !important;}
.testing{ position:absolute; top:0px;}
.movediv{transition: width 2s,
-webkit-transition: width 2s, -webkit-transform 2000s;}
.movediv:hover{margin-left: 35px;
    transform:rotate(0);
-webkit-transform:rotate(0); /* Safari */ }
```

and heres the ref for you 
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition2
for smooth transitions

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with transitions? You and [Fags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18286336/1542290) both have answered irrelevantly..

Comment: Acctuly i want to move parent div's position on mouse hover via css not css transition